# How to convert a negative decimal into hexadecimal using xslt 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to convert negative and positive decimal into hexadecimal using xslt 1.0.

There's already a topic related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280783/convert-negative-decimal-to-hexadecimal-in-xslt) but the answer is given using xslt 2.0.

I tried to reproduce the template using xslt 1.0 but it always returns an empty value.

```
    <xsl:template name="convertDecToHex">
    <xsl:param name="pInt" />
    <xsl:variable name="vMinusOneHex64"><xsl:number>18446744073709551615</xsl:number></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vCompl">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pInt &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$pInt" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vMinusOneHex64 + $pInt + 1" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="vCompl = 0">
            <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="vCompl &gt; 16">
                    <xsl:variable name="result">
                        <xsl:call-template name="convertDecToHex">
                            <xsl:with-param name="pInt" select="$vCompl div 16" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($result,substring('0123456789ABCDEF',($vCompl div 16) + 1,1))" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('',substring('0123456789ABCDEF',($vCompl div 16) + 1,1))" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Could you help me making it work?

Comment: I guess from your code and its handling of -1 that you probably want to represent negative integers in twos-complement 32 bit encoding, that is -1 becomes FFFFFFFF?

Comment: yes, this is the expected result.

Comment: I notice that `vCompl` should be `$vCompl`. Apart from that, sorry, writing complex logic in XSLT 1.0 is about as much fun as writing COBOL. Are you really limited to 1.0?

Comment: @G4ry If you want a 32-bit result, then don't use a 64-bit complement. I don't think there's an XSLT 1.0 processor that can handle such a large number.

Comment: @MichaelKay I'm not limited to XSLT 1.0 but I started with it (It's the first time I use xslt) and I would have preferred to find a solution with XSLT 1.0 instead of migrating to 2.0.

Without the solution given by michael.hor257k, I would have tried with xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a decimal number to 32-bit signed hexadecimal in pure XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:template name="dec2signedhex">
    <xsl:param name="decimal"/>
    <xsl:variable name="n">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$decimal &lt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$decimal + 4294967296"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$decimal"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="q" select="floor($n div 16)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$q">
        <xsl:call-template name="dec2signedhex">
            <xsl:with-param name="decimal" select="$q"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('0123456789ABCDEF', $n mod 16 + 1, 1)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the solution :)