# How to convert decimal no to hexadecimal in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

From the source I am getting the position number which I have to convert in hexadecimal before moving to destination. How can I code this in XSLT?

Comment: Does this question solve the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280843/how-to-convert-a-negative-decimal-into-hexadecimal-using-xslt-1

Comment: Position is a positive integer always. so will this code work? Can we use mod?

Comment: @AdyaAnuragDas If the decimal is always positive, then you can remove the part that tests for negative input.