How to convert Long datatype to Hex format in XSLT and Perform Long Parsing in XSLT. XSLT to be used in DataPower
Below is my .Net VB code.
How do we implement below code in XSLT (XSLT to be used in DataPower). Since we do not have Long datatype in XSLT, we're having tough time to implement below .Net code in XSLT. Can you please help.
Public Sub Main(args() As string)
  'Inputs are hardcoded
  Dim strLength As Integer = 8
  Dim longValue As Long = 2

  'We're trying to convert Long(819) to Hex String of Length 8
  Dim hexString As String = longValue.ToString("X" & strLength)

  'Declaring Variables
  Dim intLoop As Integer
  Dim longTempValue As Long
  Dim stringBuffer As New System.Text.StringBuilder(strLength)

  For intLoop = 0 To strLength -2
  longTempValue = Long.Parse(hexString.Substring(intLoop,2), Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
  stringBuffer.Append(Chr(longTempValue))
  intLoop+=2
  Next

  Console.WriteLine(stringBuffer.ToString())
End Sub

But Input is a Long datatype but since we considered decimal input which couldnt handle input value &H111 due to range restriction. I've checked online compiler and could get &H111 hex value as 00000111
Now lets consider hex value as input(00000111) and take 2 characters at a time 
(1)Convert string representation of a number in specified style to its 64bit signed integer equivalent 
(2)Convert to Character Code(represents particular character in a set, such as ANSI character set) 
How do we handle these conversions in XSLT? I've updated complete VB code above

Your question is not clear. If you're asking about XSLT then please provide a [mcve] showing an XML input, your XSLT attempt and the expected output. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

If you are asking how to convert a decimal number to hexadecimal (in XSLT 1.0), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46302451/3016153.

Datapower is basically XSLT 1.0 plus IBM-specific extensions. The extensions include a host of conversion functions between different data types. They are very poorly documented, but there may be something there that provides what you need.

Hi @michael.hor257k, We're using XSLT2.0. The inputs are hardcoded. We're trying to convert Long(819) to Hex String of Length 8.Executing above code will produce an output: 00000333 We can execute VB code via online compiler - https://onecompiler.com/vb/

If the inputs are hardcoded, why can't you simply hardcode them as hex values?

I've hardcoded sample values to variables for reference and the input parameters are going to vary in real time. If we can come up equivalent code in xslt, I can implement accordingly

Here is an example showing how you can convert a decimal value to hexadecimal notation with fixed 8 digits:
XML
<input>
    <decimal>0</decimal>
    <decimal>1</decimal>
    <decimal>9</decimal>
    <decimal>10</decimal>
    <decimal>15</decimal>
    <decimal>16</decimal>
    <decimal>34</decimal>
    <decimal>96</decimal>
    <decimal>178</decimal>
    <decimal>506</decimal>
    <decimal>1308</decimal>
    <decimal>9734</decimal>
    <decimal>53789</decimal>
    <decimal>786120</decimal>
</input>

XSLT 2.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
exclude-result-prefixes="math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="decimal">
            <xsl:variable name="hex-values" select="for $i in 0 to 7 return . idiv math:pow(16, $i) mod 16"/>    
            <hex>
                <xsl:value-of select="for $j in reverse($hex-values) return codepoints-to-string($j + (if($j > 9) then 55 else 48))" separator=""/>
            </hex>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <hex>00000000</hex>
   <hex>00000001</hex>
   <hex>00000009</hex>
   <hex>0000000A</hex>
   <hex>0000000F</hex>
   <hex>00000010</hex>
   <hex>00000022</hex>
   <hex>00000060</hex>
   <hex>000000B2</hex>
   <hex>000001FA</hex>
   <hex>0000051C</hex>
   <hex>00002606</hex>
   <hex>0000D21D</hex>
   <hex>000BFEC8</hex>
</output>

Naturally, with an output of fixed 8 hexadecimal digits, the input values are expected to be integers in the range of 0 to 4294967295.

Thank You Michael, that worked. But Input is a Long datatype but since we considered decimal input which couldnt handle input value &H111 due to range restriction. I've checked online compiler and could get &H111 hex value as 00000111
Now lets consider hex value as input(00000111) and take 2 characters at a time
(1)Convert string representation of a number in specified style to its 64bit signed integer equivalent
(2)Convert to Character Code(represents particular character in a set, such as ANSI character set)
How do we handle these conversions in XSLT? I've updated complete VB code above

Sorry, I have no clue what you're talking about. I don't know what kind of string representation your input XML uses and what are its rules. I suspect you need to need to do this in two steps: (1) convert the input string to a number that XSLT can understand and work with as a number; (2) convert the number to hexadecimal notation. I suggest you post a separate question about (1) and explain exactly what the input looks like. Then move to (2) as explained above.

Hi Michael - In simple terms, with above code we are able to get hexa notation. How do we convert this hexa to ASCII character encoding in XSLT?
